# Can I use reCaptcha on PHP and ASP?

Tags: php, asp-classic, dreamweaver, recaptcha

To be more clear, I have different forms on the website (it's my college's website), where they have all the forms on PHP but hey use an ASP engine to send all the info to the email assigned. My question is: on the Google website about the captcha it says to use the second code on a verify.php page but I would like to use the second code on a ASP engine. Is that possible? I tried everything, otherwise we will have to change all the engines we have to PHP.

Comment: doesn't matter what language you use, it's possible. go to reCaptcha website and check out documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely possible. How to verify a reCaptcha attempt [is publicly documented](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). The form post will have all the information you need to verify the submission about that individual user. You just need to share the private key between the two applications to make it work together.

Comment: So basically I just need to put the private key in both the PHP and the ASP engine? And then the public key only on the form page??/ Thanks

Comment: @JuanGimenez Correct. Your public key is only used to get the UI of reCaptcha loaded on the web page.

Comment: Ok last thing, I dont know wha code to use to connect both sites because one is PHP and the verify is ASP...

Comment: @JGimnZ I think you're making the problem more complex than it is. PHP form doesn't matter, since your PHP form doesn't generate any part of the reCaptcha. It's just a javascript file that runs on the UI. Then when you post the information to your ASP script, you can send a request from that server to recaptcha to figure out if the user solved the captcha correctly or not. There's a graphic of the flow on [the documentation site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

Comment: I am just asking if you can tell me the code I need to use on my ASP part because I have been trying to fix it and none of the codes I have tried work. Thanks

Comment: @JGimnZ "I have been trying to fix it and none of the codes I have tried work" - edit your post with the code you're having issues with and explain where you're running into problems (remove the recaptcha secret key if you're posting that part of the code). Then the entire community can help solve your issue.

Comment: The code is just an engine that grabs the info from the fields on the form and send it to the email. The PHP page with the form works, but the action of the form is the ASP engine, well there the problem, I can't find the code to link both pages. Should I just put it on the PHP page? Or as I thought, I need to put it in both???